# How to interrupt a subprocess launched by sh?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to process output from a subprocess and decide to terminate that subprocess once I received sufficient output. My program logic decides when we have enough input.

Example: Wait for a Udev event

```
try:
  for event in sh.udevadm('monitor', _iter=True):
    if event matches usb stick added:
      print("Ok, I will work with that USB stick you just plugged in!")
      break
except:
  pass

print("I copy stuff on your USB stick now!")
```

The 'break' terminates the process but I cannot catch the exception:

[image: Unhandled exception]

What is the correct way to terminate a subprocess or how can I handle the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way using interactive callbacks.

http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#interactive-callbacks

Pretty neat, I think.

```
def wait_for_plugged_in_drive(self):
    print("Plugin an external HDD or USB stick.")

    sh.udevadm.monitor(_out=self._scan_and_terminate).wait()

def _scan_and_terminate(self, line, stdin, process):

    match = re.search('add\\s+/.*/block/sd./(sd..)', line)

    if match is not None:

        self.device = '/dev/' + match.group(1)
        print("USB stick recognized {0}".format(self.device))

        process.terminate()
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're better off using `subprocess.Popen` directly instead of `sh` library.

Something similar to:

```
$ cat udevtest.py
import subprocess

try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["udevadm", "monitor"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                                    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while True:
        line = proc.stdout.readline()
        if line == "" or len(line) == 0:
            break  # EOF

        if line.find("pci0000") != -1:  # your trigger
            print("TRIGGER %s" % line.strip())
            break

    proc.terminate()
    proc.wait()
except Exception, e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Good to see that the alternative to sh would still be very straightforward.